# Handling race conditions in mysql db

Tags: mysql, database, database-design, locking

I am working on creating a wallet which will have some credit and debit transactions.

DB schema:

[image]

On every debit request, I am checking if the debit amount is less than or equal to the total amount in my wallet. The total amount will be the sum of all credits and will subtract the sum of all debits from it. Credit will work fine as I am not saving any total amount in the table, hence no race condition will happen. But at the time of debit I need to get the total amount and have some validations on it, then create a new debit entry.

One solution that came to my mind was to have a wallet lock for debits, i.e when a debit request comes I will take a lock for it save it in-memory and when another debit request comes I will check for the lock.

Is there some better solution for this. Another solution came to my mind was of table row lock, but I am not sure if I can use that for my case.

Please help me with a better and decent solution for this. Thanks in advance.

Comment: are you using SQL transactions to wrap your queries currently? It might help to show your current code.

Comment: yeah all the queries will be in a transaction. I don't have a code handy right now. Just figuring out ways in which it can be done

Answer (score 0):

```
BEGIN;
a bunch of UPDATEs to subtract money from one place and add it to another.
if overdrawn, ROLLBACK
else COMMIT
```

You may need a little more to help avoid deadlocks:

```
BEGIN;
SELECT ... FOR UPDATE;  -- the rows you need to look at and may need to update
... (tests)
UPDATE ... -- subtract money from here
UPDATE ... -- add that money to there
COMMIT;
```

Be sure to check for errors at every step.